# Formula or Macro for Open Office calc to retrieve Comments (annotation) from a Cell

Tags: excel, formula, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I need to harvest and colate data from an oOcalc workbook.
Part of the information is presented as comments on the cell.

I cant figure out a formula to do it and Im not familiar with oOcalc DOM's to manipulate the item.

Hope someone can help me out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just had to figure this one out myself, so here is a macro that will copy the comments of cells in one sheet to actual cells in another sheet.
It could be better, but it gets the job done, so its not worth putting anymore (of my) time into!

```
REM ****** BASIC *********

Sub ExtractCommentAnnotationThings

Dim myDoc as Object
Dim originalSheet as Object
Dim newSheet as Object
Dim originalCell as Object
Dim newCell as Object
Dim commentString As String

REM DEFINE VAR FOR OUR LOOP
Dim iTargetRow, iTargetColumn As Long

Const kEndRow = 950
Const kEndColumn = 20

REM SET DOC
myDoc = ThisComponent

REM GET SHEET
originalSheet = myDoc.Sheets(0)
newSheet = myDoc.Sheets(1)

REM START LOOP
For iTargetRow = 0 To kEndRow: DoEvents
For iTargetColumn = 0 To kEndColumn: DoEvents
    originalCell = originalSheet.getCellByPosition(iTargetColumn,iTargetRow)
    REM commentString = Trim(originalCell.Comment.Text)
    If originalCell.Annotation.isVisible = True Then

        commentString = originalCell.getAnnotation().String

        newCell = newSheet.getCellByPosition(iTargetColumn,iTargetRow)
        newCell.String = commentString
    End If      
Next
Next
REM CONTINUE LOOP

End Sub
```

Set the `kEndRow` and `kEndColumn` to include only the range of cells you want copied.
Set the `originalSheet` and `newSheet`appropriately as well (might need to create a new sheet first), so they're copied where you want them to be.

Hope it helps!